# How does one insert timestampz's into postgres using spring jdbc

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a table in postgres called retailPrices that has a column of type timestampz. I can insert a timestamp into it using the shell and programmatically using jdbc by concatenating it into a query and passing it into jdbc.update(). However I've been enlightened to the better way of running statements through jdbc which is through the use of the varargs overload as shown below.

```java
ZonedDateTime ts = ZonedDateTime.now();
String tsFormatted = ts.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
String insertRetailPrice = "insert into retailprices values (?, ?, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ?);";
int retailPriceAffectedRows = jdbcTemplate.update(insertRetailPrice, SKU, price, tsFormatted);
```

However I keep getting runtime exceptions when specifically trying to insert timestampz's. I've tried it with and without the prefix "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" with both the ZonedDateTime, ts, and the string, tsFormatted, with no avail.